# Google Sheets - formula to return N first values from range A where MAX(range B)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, range, max, formula

F1:N1 with random numbers (can have duplicates).
F2:N2 with sorted numbers.
Need a formula to fill in A1:C1 with values from F2:N2 where F1:N1 has a maximum value.
In the example it should be 1,8,3 from F2:N2 - according to 9,9,8 from F1:N1.

---

```
_ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
1 ? ? ?     9 3 8 1 5 5 3 9 8
2           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

Comment: If it is Google Sheets, you can do it by sorting...I haven't time right now but suspect a colleague may oblige

Comment: Done - can you confirm whether it should have Google Sheets tag plz? According to the title, it should have.

Comment: Sorry Tom I cannot add tag "sheet" or "googlesheet" as it requires to have a 1500 reputation.

Comment: Have added the tag 'google-sheets' - plz let us know if it isn't appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Tom, all good! Also thanks for your answer - it solved my issue!

Comment: That's great. Looking at it again, you can actually omit the 'Limit 1' because there are only two rows in the final array and Offset 1 will give the second one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody has jumped in to offer a Google Sheets solution so here is one:

```
=query(transpose(sortn(transpose(F1:N2),3,,1,false,2,true)),"select Col1,Col2,Col3 limit 1 offset 1")
```

In A1. This is a self-expanding formula so does not need to be filled across and does not need helper rows.

[image]

**EDIT**

'Limit 1' may be omitted in the above formula as mentioned in the comment.

Also this is a little shorter:

```
=transpose(query(sortn(transpose(F1:N2),3,,1,false,2,true),"Select Col2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a "helper row" to create a list of unique ranks:

```
F3:  =RANK(F1,$F$1:$N$1)+COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1)-1
  and fill right to N3
```

Since your values in `F2:N2` are sequential `{1...8}`, you can use this formula:

```
A1:  =MATCH(SMALL($F$3:$N$3,COLUMNS($A:A)),$F$3:$N$3,0)
  and fill right to C1
```

If the values in `F2:N2` are random, then you can use this:

```
A1:   =INDEX($F$2:$N$2,1,MATCH(SMALL($F$3:$N$3,COLUMNS($A:A)),$F$3:$N$3,0))
   and fill right to C1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Excel Solution with helper cells]

Formula in A1 `= INDEX($F$2:$N$2,MATCH(COLUMN(A1),$F$3:$N$3,0))`  and is dragged till C1
Formula in F3 `= RANK(F1,$F$1:$N$1)+COUNTIF($F$1:F1,F1)-1` and is dragged till N3